# PostgreSQL Filter condition by subquery output

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the query with subquery for result output as `yesterday_sum` column. I need to filter only rows where `yesterday_sum > 1` but can't add `HAVING sum(p.profit_percent) / :workDays > 1 AND yesterday_sum > 1` because `yesterday_sum` is not part of the `GROUP BY`. And I can't add a condition for `positions p` because `yesterday_sum` is not the `positions` column.

```
SELECT u.id                              AS id,
       u.nickname                        AS title,
       sum(p.profit_percent) / :workDays AS middle,
       (
           SELECT sum(ps.profit_percent)
           FROM positions ps
           WHERE ps.user_id = u.id
             AND ps.open_at BETWEEN
               :dateYesterday AND
               :dateYesterday + INTERVAL '1 day'
           GROUP BY (ps.user_id)
       )                                 AS yesterday_sum
FROM positions p
         INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = p.user_id
    AND p.profit_percent IS NOT NULL
    AND p.parent_ticket IS NULL
    AND p.close_at IS NOT NULL
    AND p.open_at BETWEEN :dateFrom AND :dateTo
GROUP BY (u.id, u.nickname)
HAVING sum(p.profit_percent) / :workDays > 1
ORDER BY middle DESC;
```

How can I get rid of rows with `yesterday_sum` column less than 1 and NULL?

Comment: Can you share a sample input table and corresponding expected output table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the column `yesterday_sum` in a `WHERE` clause you can produce the named column by placing the query as a subquery of the main one. Then, filtering is trivial.

For example, you can do:

```
select *
from (
  SELECT u.id                              AS id,
       u.nickname                        AS title,
       sum(p.profit_percent) / :workDays AS middle,
       (
           SELECT sum(ps.profit_percent)
           FROM positions ps
           WHERE ps.user_id = u.id
             AND ps.open_at BETWEEN
               :dateYesterday AND
               :dateYesterday + INTERVAL '1 day'
           GROUP BY (ps.user_id)
       )                                 AS yesterday_sum
  FROM positions p
         INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = p.user_id
    AND p.profit_percent IS NOT NULL
    AND p.parent_ticket IS NULL
    AND p.close_at IS NOT NULL
    AND p.open_at BETWEEN :dateFrom AND :dateTo
  GROUP BY (u.id, u.nickname)
  HAVING sum(p.profit_percent) / :workDays > 1
) x
where yesterday_sum >= 1  -- yesterday_sum is available here
ORDER BY middle DESC;
```